# Set a variable before importing module __init.py__

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, global-variables

My Python application structure is thus:

```
run.py
app/__init.py__
app/config.py
app/<other modules in app>
```

In my `app/__init.py`, I'd like to check a variable `DEBUG_MODE` and depending on its value, start a python `Logger` if `DEBUG_MODE == False`, and simply print to console if it is `True`. My currently attempted (and not working) solution is to have three files:

app/config.py

```
DEBUG_MODE = False
```

app/__init__.py

```
app = MyApp()
from config import DEBUG_MODE
app.debug = DEBUG_MODE
if not app.debug:
    import logging
    ...
```

run.py

```
from app import config
config.DEBUG_MODE = True
from app import app
```

The problem, of course, is that by the time my code reaches `config.DEBUG_MODE=True`, the `app` module's init code has already been called because my config file is part of the app module.

How can I tell the module that I want to enable debugging *at run time* from my run.py script?

Comment: Are you going to run this from the command line?

Comment: Initially, for debugging purposes, yes. Later I will run it as CGI, in which case the DEBUG_MODE will not be set (and the file-based logging will occur). But for now, as I develop it, it will be run from the command line.

Comment: You could always use the [sys.argv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv) to get the command line arguments and handle it from within the init code.

Comment: Unfortunately this application is a Flask application and the last thing the run.py script does is start the Flask application manager (which uses commandline arguments to determine what to do). There is probably a way to re-architect this (such as waiting to set up the logging after the module has been imported), but I want to know if I can set a variable to be read by a module's \_\_init\_\_ code at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by runtime?  You could write a .ini file with the config options and handle it from within the app/__init__.py file...  I don't know how much closer to runtime you can get.  I haven't written much in python in a while, but unless i'm misunderstanding the question, if you want something to run at runtime, throw it in your `__init__.py` file.

Comment: The `__init__.py` file sets up the module, and will be always run, whether or not the application is running from a command prompt (with my run.py script), or called by CGI. Setting an .ini is no better than just hard coding `DEBUG_MODE=True` in my init file - it works, but I have to remember to delete it once we get to production. Ideally I'd like a flag I could set in my run.py that says 'run in debug mode', and if it doesn't get set, it starts the logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this problem is `config.py` being part of the `app` module and namespace - any reference to it and its variables requires the `app/__init__.py` to be evaluated first.

One way around it is to hijack the Python `__builtin__` "module", which is available to all Python modules, and add our own variable:

run.py

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.myapp_debug = True
from app import app
```

And then in the module __init__.py:

```
# app is instantiated as an Object
import __builtin__
if hasattr(__builtin__, "myapp_debug"):
    app.debug = __builtin__.myapp_debug
else:
    app.debug = False
# If debugging is off, use file-based logging:
if not app.debug:
    print "Setting up logging..."
    import logging
    ...
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but there are a lot of people don't like duck punching/monkey patching so i was holding off.  Obviously, I'm not one of those people who looks down on the practice though :P

Comment: It's not the most elegant but I'm open to alternative suggestions. One thought was to have *another* module that my `app` module imports, that I could import from my run script and modify before it gets imported by `app`... If you had any thoughts and put it into an answer I'd accept it. :-)

Comment: honestly, the easiest way IMHO is to do exactly what you did with the builtin module.  So long as any other devs you are working with don't mind you doing it :P  Introspection is one of pythons strengths, so why wouldn't you use it?